# using < redirect with csv file

Tags: c

for an engineering class i am attempting to write some code in C that calculates drag based on three input values per line of input text file, which are to be entered at terminal using a < redirect. The program is supposed to print the 3 values entered for each line then the result of calculation in 4th column.....at the moment my code only prints and calculates the final line. I know this is a simple problem, just wondering what i am doing wrong:

```
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    double cd, mass, velocity_terminal, area;
    printf("Stage 1\n");
    printf("=======\n");

    printf("mass\tvelocity\tarea\tdrag coefficient\n");


    while(scanf("%lf,%lf,%lf", &mass, &velocity_terminal, &area) == 3);
    {

        printf("%.1lf\t %.1lf\t %.3lf\t", mass, velocity_terminal, area);

        cd = (2 * mass * GRAVITY)/(DENSITY * area * velocity_terminal * velocity_terminal);
        printf("%.3lf\n", cd);
    }
```

For example if I enter:

```
43,56,22
66,88,143
12,54,65
23,67,87
```

as the text file, it will only do the final line?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Use a debugger to step through your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your while loop is incorrect.

```
while(scanf("%lf,%lf,%lf", &mass, &velocity_terminal, &area) == 3);
```

Remove the semicolon. It ends the loop without a body, then your next block is evaluated independently of the loop.

```
while(scanf("%lf,%lf,%lf", &mass, &velocity_terminal, &area) == 3)
{
    printf("%.1lf\t %.1lf\t %.3lf\t", mass, velocity_terminal, area);
    cd = (2 * mass * GRAVITY)/(DENSITY * area * velocity_terminal * velocity_terminal);
    printf("%.3lf\n", cd);
}
```

Comment: WOW.... thanks for the quick response....been bashing my head against the wall for an hour thinking i massively misunderstood something, then it was a stupid syntax error....hopefully one day i will be able to spot them as fast as you just did!! Will accept answer as soon as it will let me! You were too fast!!

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `;` at the end of the loop.

It is different from your code to what you want.

1. `while(scanf("%lf,%lf,%lf", &mass, &velocity_terminal, &area) == 3);` will keep reading the file until EOF.
2. `{...}` And the following **block statement** still could work.

Compiler won't tell you that's wrong, because in its point of view, the syntax it's correct.  :)